# How to convert list to separate int variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a list named

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Then I converted it into int -

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

My question is, how do I separate list1 to individual int variable? Like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

Comment: `list1 = list(map(int, list1)) then a,b,c = list1`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: or straight `a, b, c = map(int, list1)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, depending  if the OP wants to use the list elsewhere with the contents as ints

Comment: Thanks Sir! But how about if my list has 23 data there so I used a1 to a23. When I tried this, python says that 'too many values to unpack'. What should I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will unpack the list and assign it's content to the corresponding variables.

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a,b,c = list1
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! But how about if my list has 23 data there so I used a1 to a23. When I tried this, python says that 'too many values to unpack'. What should I do then?

Comment: python unzip the list only if the number of items in the list is same as the number variables.

Comment: Yay! My mistake, I have 24 in my lost but I onlu used 23 variables. Thanks Sir! 

Comment: Done Sir. Can I have a follow up question Sir? I already converted it but in float. And when I used some calculations, this one:  AA = (min(a1, a2) * center) + (pow(a3,2)). I got an error says that: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float".  Btw, all variables used is float, I dunno whats the problem.

Comment: is center if of type float? It's better to ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
>>> list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> a, b, c = map(int, list1)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! But how about if my list has 23 data there so I used a1 to a23. When I tried this, python says that 'too many values to unpack'. What should I do then?